# Inserting QTable in QTree

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtreeview

I would like to design a particular layout using QTable inside of QTree.  See the followng wireframe :

[image: wireframe]

Is it possible to do this, knowing that in number :

1. The first node under Dialog 1 is seperated in 3 (or maybe four).  The time, followed by an avatar icon, followed by a blue bubble with text and followed by a number (in my exemple, 75)  So, ***first question***, is it possible to have a tree node separated in four?
2. Section 2 is composed of leaf nodes and these nodes are QTable.  So, ***question number 2***, is it possible to create QTable embedded inside a QTree?

Comment: In theory, with some tricks, you can use any widget as tree element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`setItemWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreewidget.html#setItemWidget) function in order to set the widget you wish for every tree widget item you wish.

In case of a `QTreeView` you should use the [`setIndexWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) function.

Answer (score 0):

So this needs a bit to get it usable as far as getting data into the tree and subsequent tables, but it's a starting spot.

```
class tcTreeTableWidget : public QTableWidget 
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    tcTreeTableWidget() : QTableWidget() 
    {
        setColumnCount (3);

        QStringList headers;
        headers << "Table Column 1" << "Table Column 2" << "Table Column 3";
        setHorizontalHeaderLabels (headers);
        
        for (int row = 0; row < 8; ++row)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; ++col)
            {
                setRowCount (row + 1);
                setItem (row, col, new QTableWidgetItem (QString("R %1, C %2").arg(row).arg(col)));
            }
        }
    }
};

class tcTreeTableWidgetItem : public QTreeWidgetItem 
{
public:
    tcTreeTableWidgetItem (QTreeWidgetItem* p) : QTreeWidgetItem (p) 
    {
        setFirstColumnSpanned (true);
        m_tree_widget = new tcTreeTableWidget();
        treeWidget()->setItemWidget(this, 0, m_tree_widget);
    }

private:
    tcTreeTableWidget* m_tree_widget;
};


class tcMyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    tcMyWidget (QWidget* p);

protected:
    void    setupUI     ();

    QTreeWidget*          m_tree;
};


tcMyWidget::tcMyWidget (QWidget* p)
    : QWidget (p)
{
    setupUI();
}

void tcMyWidget::setupUI()
{
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

    mainLayout->addWidget (m_tree = new QTreeWidget (this));
    m_tree->setColumnCount (4);
    
    QStringList headers;
    headers << "Tree Column 1" << "Tree Column 2" << "Tree Column 3" << "Tree Column 4";
    m_tree->setHeaderLabels (headers);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem *pitem;
        pitem = new QTreeWidgetItem (m_tree);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        {
            pitem->setText (j, QString("R %1, C %2").arg(i).arg(j));
        }
        tcTreeTableWidgetItem* ptitem = new tcTreeTableWidgetItem (pitem);
    }
}
```

[image: Tables in Trees]